# How to add content title as dropdown list for exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I have a node ABC and using view where content is of type ABC. I have content title as a field in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

What is the way in which I can get a drop down for field content title in the filter criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a hook_form_alter with a custom module like this:

```
    function mytools_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    //unset($form['average']);
    $form['average'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => array(0 => t('<any>'), 20 => '*', 40 => '**', 60 => '***', 80 => '****', 100 => '*****'),
      '#default_value' => 0,
      '#title' => t('The average vote is more than'),
    );
  }
}
```

Where the form_id is your current views form ID (you can see it with firebug in your code).

Comment: but how can populate the content:title values into this custom select list option ? Is it through query?

Comment: yes, you have to create a query who return an array valid for the #options value of the form